# How to listen for a property value change from within a usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-runtime

I have created a new user control.  I would like to listen for when the Visibility property has changed so that I can do some extra work at the same time.  I know that it is a dependency property, but it isn't one I created, so I am struggling to understand how to hook into it.  In WinRT apps, there is not [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which seems to be the most common way to do this.  I also tried creating a new dependency property that registered to the existing property name, but that callback was never fired.

I have to believe that there is some way for a dependency object to listen for it's own property changes.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I have used something like this in my user control. You can then subscribe to the `VisibilityChanged` event. Note that I am using the `new` keyword on the property.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The current visiblity of this user control.
    /// </summary>
    private Visibility _visibility;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the visibility of a UIElement.
    /// A UIElement that is not visible is not rendered and does not communicate its desired size to layout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A value of the enumeration. The default value is Visible.</returns>
    public new Visibility Visibility
    {
        get { return _visibility; }
        set
        {
            bool differ = false;
            if (value != _visibility)
            {
                _visibility = value;
                differ = true;
            }

            base.Visibility = value;

            if (differ)
            {
                RaiseVisibilityChanged(value);
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when the <see cref="Visibility"/> property changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<VisibilityChangedEventArgs> VisibilityChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="VisibilityChanged"/> event of this command bar.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="visibility">The new visibility value.</param>
    private void RaiseVisibilityChanged(Visibility visibility)
    {
        if (VisibilityChanged != null)
        {
            VisibilityChanged(this, new VisibilityChangedEventArgs(visibility));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the arguments for the <see cref="SampleViewModel.VisibilityChanged"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class VisibilityChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The new visibility.
        /// </summary>
        public Visibility NewVisibility { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="VisibilityChangedEventArgs"/> class.
        /// <param name="newVisibility">The new visibility.</param>
        /// </summary>
        public VisibilityChangedEventArgs(Visibility newVisibility)
        {
            this.NewVisibility = newVisibility;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is awesome. I did notice that it doesn't handle the initial visibility state of my usercontrol properly; it seems to think that the control is visible when it is loaded even though the XAML containing the control set the control to be collapsed initially. I suspect that I did something wrong or it's an easy fix though.